# capture text when Ctrl + C in c#

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to while running an .Net application in the system tray that when a person presses control + c in a text outside, the application capture it from Clipboard?

Comment: Check http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/NetKeyLogger.aspx on how you can capture when ctrl+C is pressed.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to monitor the contents of the clipboard, this [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.clipboard.getdata.aspx) should get you started.

Something as simple as a [Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) object which checks if the contents has changed should be more than sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

You could just run a timer and have it check the clipboard contents on tick. This way you would capture even if the user right click -> copy.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Register Hot Key function at a system level, or Global System Hooks http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/globalsystemhook.aspx

AutoHotKey is an free application that basically does this http://www.autohotkey.com/ if you are looking for an easy solution.